# Deprecated casts in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am using `Code::Blocks` for learning C++. Consider the following code:

**C**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int i = 0;
    int* j = (int*)&i;
}
```

The cast I have used in the above program has been deprecated in C++ (if I'm correct about this), but was followed in C. The Code::Blocks IDE doesn't show me any warning for this code. I know that C++ supports the explicit casts such as `const_cast`, `static_cast`, etc.

My question is: Are there any free IDE available on the internet that show warning for such deprecated syntax?

Comment: I'm sure you can switch some additional warning flags on somewhere in the settings

Comment: It is usually not the IDE (unless it's got a clever code analyzer plugged in) which issues warning, it is compiler's job. If you are interested in the design/editing time checking, the Visual Studio 2012 products do that very well. The Express edition is free.

Comment: C-style casts have not been deprecated.

Comment: Note that "deprecated" is a specific term in the C++ standard. In that context it doesn't mean, "some (book/tutorial/dude on the internet/compiler warning) told me to use something else instead" ;-) So even if C-style casts are deprecated by some dude on the internet, they certainly aren't deprecated by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also can enable those warnings in Code::Blocks. You need to add the compiler flag -Wold-style-cast for that. This is how I did it in Code::Blocks:

- Go to Project in the top menu
- Choose Build Options
- Compiler Settings tab (Default selected)
- Other Options tab
- In the text field enter: -Wold-style-cast

Then you will get output like this with your code:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming CodeBlocks is compiling using gcc. You can enable a warning by adding the compiler flag `-Wold-style-cast`. You might have to poke around in CodeBlocks to figure out where to put that flag. You can also enable a bunch more warnings with `-Wall`.

Comment: Yes i am using Mingw gcc-4.3.2 compiler.

Comment: Note that in spite of the name, `-Wall` does not include `-Wold-style-cast`!

Comment: Still thank you. And Yeah `-Wall doesn't include `-Wold-style-cast`. But can I include both `-Wall` and '-Wold-style-cast'?

Comment: @buzzinga yes, you can, along with bunch of other options